# StringBuilder AppendFormat IEnumarble

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have a string builder and a list of object ,

```
int[] values = new int[] {1,2};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}", values );
```

I see an IntelliSense  error

> None existing arguments in format string

why am I seeing this error ,and how should I 
I use a list parameters inside the `AppendFormat`

Comment: You also have the option of doing `builder.Append(String.Join(", ", values));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload of `AppendFormat` that you are currently using (or that the compiler decided to use) has the following signature:

```
public StringBuilder AppendFormat(string format, object arg0)
```

It is expecting a single argument and therefore a `format` that contains two arguments (`"{0}, {1}"`) is invalid.

Your intention is to pass the array as multiple arguments, the overload that you need to use is the following:

```
public StringBuilder AppendFormat(string format, params object[] args)
```

Note that the second argument is an `object[]`, not `int[]`. To make your code use this overload, you need to convert the `int` array into an `object` array like this:

```
builder.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}", values.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in an object array instead of an int array. Otherwise it thinks the array object is the parameter for arg0.

```
object[] values = new object[] { 1, 2 };
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}", values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the list using `foreach`

```
int[] values = new int[] {1,2};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (int val in values)
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}\n", val);         
}
Console.WriteLine(builder);
```

See the [Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ItVLSA).

In your case, you used:

```
builder.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}", values );
```

as you are passing 2 arguments `{0}, {1}` which is invalid for a single value of `values` as the outcome.